# Setting max. upload size for Archetypes FileField

Tags: plone

How one can limit the size of a file uploaded to Archetypes FileField?

Comment: Other than using the `isMaxSize` validator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATContentTypes registeres a `checkFileMaxSize` validator:

```py
from Products.validation.config import validation
from Products.validation.validators.SupplValidators import MaxSizeValidator

validation.register(MaxSizeValidator('checkFileMaxSize',
                                     maxsize=zconf.ATFile.max_file_size))
```

where `zconf.ATFile.max_file_size` defaults to "no limit" but you can alter that by copying `Products/ATContentTypes/etc/atcontenttypes.conf.in` to `$INSTANCE_HOME/etc/atcontentypes.conf` and setting the `max_file_size` parameter:

```
<archetype ATFile>
   # maximum file size in byte, kb or mb
   max_file_size 10mb
</archetype>
```

(the format supports `gb` as well, but the default file doesn't include that in the list).

If you have custom File fields (the above only applies to the default Archetypes ATFile schema), you can either re-use that validator or create your own. To reuse the above validator, simply add it to the `validators` attribute:

```py
from Products.validation import V_REQUIRED

FileField('yourfilefield',
    # ...
    validators = (
        ('isNonEmptyFile', V_REQUIRED),
        ('checkFileMaxSize', V_REQUIRED)
    ),
)
```

To use a different maximum size that you configure independently, use the same `MaxSizeValidator` that ATContentTypes uses and register it under a new name, then use that validator instead of the `'checkFileMaxSize'` validator; the value you specify is the number of [mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibytes) (1024<sup>2</sup> bytes):

```py
from Products.validation.config import validation
from Products.validation.validators.SupplValidators import MaxSizeValidator

validation.register(MaxSizeValidator('checkFileMax50mb', 50))
```

Comment: To help protect against resource hogs, if you are running Plone behind nginx, you could check the declared size of the request immediately, before passing it to Plone. See 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

You'll probably want to handle the error in nginx too:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page